# How can I create a usage-based subscription with a 0$ flat rate (pure per-usage subscription)?

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to create a subscription-based flow in Stripe that lets the users only be charged if they use the platform, and based purely on their usage.

For example: If they consume 3 products, that'll be 3*(priceOfProduct)$. But, if they don't consume any product, it'll be a 0$ bill for that month.

Is it even possible to achieve this using Stripe?

I've tried creating a metered-usage product, but when I try creating a Subscription object with 0 quantity of it it throws an error.

I've also tried setting up a checkout session but with no progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried creating a metered-usage product, but when I try creating a Subscription object with 0 quantity of it it throws an error.

This is because [metered usage](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/usage-based) calculates based on [reported usage](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/usage-based#report), not `quantity`. Setting quantity is for licensed pricing, and trying to set it for metered prices will result in an error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "You cannot set the quantity for metered plans.",
        "param": "quantity",
        "request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_12345",
        "type": "invalid_request_error"
    }
}
```

You can do what you're asking, but you'll need to report usage each month (based on whatever units are appropriate). You can review the guidance more [modelling your product & pricing](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/usage-based#product-modeling) to match your needs, which sounds like a single rate per unit with no flat fees or graduated/tiered pricing.

Comment: Thank you, this guided me in the right direction.
Basically I had to:
 1. Create the subscription with just the price id of the metered product.
 2. Make use of a usage_record with the subscription_item id to set the quantity when needed.